# review form do not show up after clicking on "Be the first one to review"?

Tags: magento-1.5, magento

i have checked that review is both enabled from Advance tab under system -> configuration and also from catalog tab.
also i have changed the files with original one but still not getting the form on frontend :( Although link to show review is showing .

can anyone please help ?

DO category settings like anchor set to NO has any impact on it ?

i did even replace complete folders of layout and template even then it didn't change. But when I commented app/design/frontend/mythemefolder,
it did show up.

But how can i show it on mytheme ?

Comment: But how would i get it on my theme folder :( and what problem it can be ??? i am using magento 1.5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess someone played with my style sheet and i found that this class ".product-collateral" in stylesheet was given "display = NOne"
it took me too long as i was examining the code but anyhow problem solved.